# Why can I not pass my class pointer to my visitor class? It says there are no matching functions

Tags: c++, visitor-pattern

Essentially this visitor class was working until I tried to add another class to it.

The is the visitor class I am going to refer to:

### Visitor.h

```
#ifndef Visitor_h__
#define Visitor_h__

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace Ph2_System
{
    class SystemController;
}

namespace GUI
{
    class SystemControllerWorker;
}

class HwDescriptionVisitor
{
  public:
     //SystemController
    virtual void visit( Ph2_System::SystemController& pSystemController ) {} //This one works

    //SystemControllerWorker
    virtual void visit( GUI::SystemControllerWorker& pSystemControllerWorker ) {}
}
```

This is the class which tries to call a visit on it:

### SystemControllerWorker.h

```
#include "../HWInterface/Visitor.h"
#include "Model/settings.h"

namespace GUI
{

    class SystemControllerWorker
    {
      public:

        SystemControllerWorker(Settings &config);
        ~SystemControllerWorker();

         void accept( HwDescriptionVisitor& pVisitor ) const {
          pVisitor.visit( *this ); // this is where I get my error message
          for ( auto& cShelve : fShelveVector )
              cShelve->accept( pVisitor );
         }
      private:
        Settings& m_Settings; //takes in the above &config in the contructor
```

The only difference between the `SystemController` and `SystemControllerWorker` is the first one doesn't take in any arguments, and this one does. Any idea why I get this error message:

```
error: no matching function for call to "HwDescriptionVisitor::visit(const GUI::SystemControllerWorker&)"
           pVisitor.visit( *this );
```

Or what this might mean?

Comment: you are in `const` qualified member function, hence the `this` is of `const SystemControllerWorker*` type, hence the `*this` expression evaluates to `const SystemControllerWorker&`, while your target method expects non-const lvalue reference. Depending on what `visit`ing is permitted to do, you can either remove the `const` qualifier from `accept` method OR add `const` qualifier to `Ph2_System::SystemController&` argument of `visit` method

Comment: That should be an answer, since it's... well... the answer.

Comment: Haha yeah that was the answer, adding const worked!

Comment: `Visitor_h__` is a reserved identifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it is good to read the entire error message, a compiler is really willing to help you understand why it had to fail:

```
main.cpp: In member function 'void SystemControllerWorker::accept(HwDescriptionVisitor&) const':
main.cpp:15:29: error: no matching function for call to 'HwDescriptionVisitor::visit(const SystemControllerWorker&)'
         pVisitor.visit(*this);
                             ^
main.cpp:15:29: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:8:10: note: void HwDescriptionVisitor::visit(SystemControllerWorker&)
     void visit(SystemControllerWorker& pSystemControllerWorker) {}
          ^
main.cpp:8:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const SystemControllerWorker' to 'SystemControllerWorker&'
```

That last `note` is most important; it says: *"no known conversion for argument 1 from **'const SystemControllerWorker'** to **'SystemControllerWorker&'**"*

You might be wondering why the `this` is of a `const SystemControllerWorker` type, not simply `SystemControllerWorker`. This is because the method that calls `pVisitor.visit(*this)` is itself marked as `const`:

```
void accept( HwDescriptionVisitor& pVisitor ) const {
//                                 right here ~~~~^
```

That makes the `this` a pointer to `const SystemControllerWorker` and *dereferencing* it results in a `const` type as well.

Depending on what visiting should be permitted to do, you can either remove the `const` qualifier from the `accept` member function

*OR*

add a `const` qualifier to  the `SystemController&` parameter of the `visit` member function, like below:

```
virtual void visit( const Ph2_System::SystemController& pSystemController ) {}
//             here ~~~~^
```